# node wait for iteration to complete before callback

Tags: node.js, parallel-processing, aws-lambda, iteration, async.js

I have a lambda function in node.js to send a push notification.

In that function I need to iterate through my users sending a notification for each one prior to the callback.

Ideally I would like the iteration to perform in parallel.

What would be the best way to do this?

My code is currently as follows but it does not work as expected because the last user is not always the last to be handled:

```
var apnProvider = new apn.Provider(options);

var iterationComplete = false;

for (var j = 0; j < users.length; j++) {
    if (j === (users.length - 1)) {
        iterationComplete = true;
    }

    var deviceToken = users[j].user_device_token;
    var deviceBadge = users[j].user_badge_count;

    var notification = new apn.Notification();

    notification.alert = message;

    notification.contentAvailable = 1;

    notification.topic = "com.example.Example";

    apnProvider.send(notification, [deviceToken]).then((response) => {

        if (iterationComplete) {
            context.succeed(event);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Promise.all` instead - map each `user`'s associated `apnProvider.send` call to a `Promise` in an array, and when all `Promise`s in the array are resolved, call the callback:

```
const apnProvider = new apn.Provider(options);
const userPromises = users.map((user) => {
  const deviceToken = user.user_device_token;
  const deviceBadge = user.user_badge_count;
  const notification = new apn.Notification();
  notification.alert = message;
  notification.contentAvailable = 1;
  notification.topic = "com.example.Example";
  return apnProvider.send(notification, [deviceToken]);
})
Promise.all(userPromises)
  .then(() => {
    context.succeed(event);
  })
  .catch(() => {
    // handle errors
  });
```

Comment: thanks you.  I have not used promises before.  seems to be working well.